# Invalid identifier in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a many-to-many relationship between `EnfInspPrgm` entity and `EnfInspPmSc` entity.

Here are the entity classes

```
    public class EnfInspPrgm implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name="PRM_ID")
        private long prmId;

        @Column(name="AREA_ID")
        private long areaId;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to EnfInspPmSc
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="enfInspPrgm")
        private List<EnfInspPmSc> enfInspPmScs;

        public EnfInspPrgm() {
        }

        public long getPrmId() {
            return this.prmId;
        }

        public void setPrmId(long prmId) {
            this.prmId = prmId;
        }

        public long getAreaId() {
            return this.areaId;
        }

        public void setAreaId(long areaId) {
            this.areaId = areaId;
        }

        public List<EnfInspPmSc> getEnfInspPmScs() {
            return this.enfInspPmScs;
        }

        public void setEnfInspPmScs(List<EnfInspPmSc> enfInspPmScs) {
            this.enfInspPmScs = enfInspPmScs;
        }

        public EnfInspPmSc addEnfInspPmSc(EnfInspPmSc enfInspPmSc) {
            getEnfInspPmScs().add(enfInspPmSc);
            enfInspPmSc.setEnfInspPrgm(this);

            return enfInspPmSc;
        }

        public EnfInspPmSc removeEnfInspPmSc(EnfInspPmSc enfInspPmSc) {
            getEnfInspPmScs().remove(enfInspPmSc);
            enfInspPmSc.setEnfInspPrgm(null);

            return enfInspPmSc;
        }

    }

@Entity
@Table(name="ENF_INSP_PM_SC")
public class EnfInspPmSc implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to InspectionSource
        @ManyToOne(optional=false)
        @JoinColumn(name="ENF_INSP_SOURCE_ID")
        private InspectionSource inspectionSource;

    @Column(name="ENF_INSP_PRM_SRC_ID")
    private long enfInspPrmSrcId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRM_ID")
    private EnfInspPrgm enfInspPrgm;

    public EnfInspPmSc() {
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "REF_ENF_INSP_SOURCE")
public class InspectionSource implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENF_INSP_SOURCE_ID")
    private Integer id;


    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY_USER_ID")
    private User createdUser;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MODIFIED_BY_USER_ID")
    private User modifiedUser;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getCreatedUser() {
        return createdUser;
    }

    public void setCreatedUser(User createdUser) {
        this.createdUser = createdUser;
    }

    public String getCreatedByName() {
        return createdByName;
    }

    public void setCreatedByName(String createdByName) {
        this.createdByName = createdByName;
    }

    public User getModifiedUser() {
        return modifiedUser;
    }

    public void setModifiedUser(User modifiedUser) {
        this.modifiedUser = modifiedUser;
    }

}
```

I am creating a JPA repository for selecting the `EnfInspPrgm` entities. But itis  causing an error

```
Invalid identifier for enfInspPrgm, ENF_INSP_SOURCE_ID
```

Please help me and resolve this issue.

Comment: Where is your `InspectionSource` entity code?

Comment: add the inspectionSource entity..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems missing some declaration. For example EnfInspPrgm is not annotatted with @Entity.

Also, In EnfInspPmSc you didn't put getter and setter for the fields. Put getEnfInspPrgm and setEnfInspPrgm. Do the same for the other fields.

Note that JPA declartions will be translated in all cases into native sql. The owner of the relationship is always the many side which has a FK to the one side. So, If EnfInspPmSc don't have those setters and getters you won't be able to get access to any data in both tables.